# Inout variable set in in UIAlertAction closure not changing value

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a function with an `inout` paramter: `enabled: Bool`
The object I'm referencing (I know `inout` isn't technically a reference...) and setting using this method is a stored property on a `UIViewController`
`var enabled = false`

I have multiple booleans triggering different things, and I want to use one method to set them.

So I call the method:

`self.determineEnabled(&self.enabled)`

Below is the code, and I've used comments to explain whats happening

Code:

```
func determineEnabled(inout enabled: Bool) {

    if enabled == false {
        enabled = true
   //self.enabled equals true now. This works. Its not in a closure...
    } else {

        let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "Disable", style: .Destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            enabled = false
            print(self.enabled)
            //This doesn't work. the inout variable equals FALSE
            //self.enabled equals true
            //If I set self.enabled = false.. Then it works, but I'm using a method because my app could have dozens of these enabled bools on this view controller.

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Change Bool", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alertController.addAction(delete)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

My app is obviously a more complex than this chunk of code, but I can verify this problem exists within this chuck of code.

I'll be honest that I don't thoroughly understand closures as much as I'd like..

But if I can use `self.enabled` to correctly change the value of enabled, what is stopping swift from changing setting the inout enabled variable?

UPDATE:

Here is a link from the docs that specifically mention my problem:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545

"There is no copy-out at the end of closures or nested functions. This means if a closure is called after the function returns, any changes that closure makes to the in-out parameters do not get copied back to the original."

Swift evolution on the topic:
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0035-limit-inout-capture.md

Comment: I don't think it's possible given this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28286993/4096655 I also actually previously asked a ? on SO regarding the frame of a method being always available to a long executing closure and it is, but the arguments are now constant, http://stackoverflow.com/a/34915207/4096655

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, functions are closures. Closures capture state. At the time we encounter the anonymous function containing the code `print(self.enabled)`, `self.enabled` is `true`. We know that, because if it were not, we wouldn't be here at all (we'd be in the first wing of the condition, `if enabled == false`). Therefore when `print(self.enabled)` is later actually executed, it will print `true`, because that was the state of things when it captured its value.

Comment: very nicely explained, ty!

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. However no matter what, the uialertaction handler cannot change the input enabled. So if I check ten mins afterwards still same result. Once sent to true in 'if enabled == false' that property never changes

Comment: We've already captured this value. It isn't "live" while you change it elsewhere.

Comment: You might find this discussion of mine interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30060801/341994

Comment: @matt I'm curious, you mentioned you would post it inside dev forums. Did you end up doing so? I'll admit I'm a little nonplused that swift doesn't have a way to do this

Comment: I never understood what you were trying to do, so I don't understand what "do this" means. I was just explaining the particular behavior you were asking about.

Comment: @matt I essentially was looking for a way to retain the reference to the inout variable. Per your answer and the links I've added as updates I now understand that I didn't know what "do this" meant either haha. To sum it up the answer for me was: the function has already returned and store the inout parameter value.

Comment: But what I don't understand is _why_ "I essentially was looking for a way to retain the reference to the inout variable" - i.e., what are your larger architectural goals. It is possible there's some simple Swifty way to do what you want to do, if only I knew what it was.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I've marked yours as the answer @matt. Thanks for being willing to perhaps help me find a "Swifty" way to do this. Though I would say that anything further would be out of the scope for this question. I didn't understand why the value was changing for the inout parameter, and your answer clarifies why. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself in your question;

> I know inout isn't technically a reference

From the Apple Swift book

> An in-out parameter has a value that is passed *in* to the function,
>   is modified by the function and is passed back *out* of the function
>   to replace the original value.

You are modifying the value in a closure that executes some time later when the user interacts with the alert.  At this point `determineEnabled` has already returned and stored the value of the `inout` parameter.

If an `inout` parameter *was* a reference, like a C-style pointer, then `enabled` would be pointing to a chunk of memory that stores `self.enabled` and when the value was modified in the closure, `self.enabled` would be modified.

You can see how this works if you create a simple class with a boolean property and then pass an instance of this class to your `determineEnabled` function (without using `inout`).  Since objects *are* passed by reference, a subsequent update to the object's property in the closure will be visible anywhere that same object reference is used;